# youtube subscribe button inline

Tags: html, button, youtube, inline

I am trying to get the buttons in the below snippet inline. How can I do this?

```html
<p style="clear:both;">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <h3>Subscribe to all our free videos </h3>
    <a Subscribe to all our free videos : class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UC1s3K1bQQDwvo3Qcaxg3Zjg" data-layout="full" style="display-inline" data-count="hidden"></a>
    <a class="button-big salmon rounded99" style="display-inline" "href="#" onclick="history.back();">Go Back a page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `h3` element is 100% width by default. Making this inline means it will take as much space as it needs, and allow for other elements to be placed alongside it.

As a side note, I would refrain from using inline styling at any time, as it can cause issues with specificity selection.

```css
h3{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<p style="clear:both;">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<h3>Subscribe to all our free videos </h3>
<a Subscribe to all our free videos : class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UC1s3K1bQQDwvo3Qcaxg3Zjg" data-layout="full" style="display-inline" data-count="hidden"></a>
<a class="button-big salmon rounded99" style="display-inline" "href="#" onclick="history.back();">Go Back a page</a>
```

## Result

[image]

---

you may also need to add a vertical-align:top to your a tag as well in order for your link to align properly:

[image]

Comment: So replaced the h3 with just text still no joy. Also change the inline-block and again no joy

Comment: @PaulReynolds: Have edited my answer to include a screenshot. Are you not getting that?

Comment: have no idea then. it works on here but no the site. http://activelifeoutdoors.com/Weight-loss/quick-stuffed-sundries-chicken-breasts/

Comment: @PaulReynolds: I believe that is caused by your <br> tag you have.

Comment: taken out... still not happening, bloody night mare

Comment: No joy : but i am going to give up !!                                                              <a Subscribe to all our free videos : class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UC1s3K1bQQDwvo3Qcaxg3Zjg" data-layout="full" style="vertical-align:baseline; display:inline-block" data-count="hidden"></a>
<a class="button-big salmon rounded99" style="display-inline; vertical-align:top" "href="#" onclick="history.back();">Go Back a page</a>

Comment: euh back to this again.. grr